# Facebook like button and OAuth Access

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am connecting to the Facebook API using [HybridAuth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) on the server side (backend is written in PHP). This is for a SaaS publishing application that is hosted on our servers. I understand the mechanics of OAuth and that once I accquire the appropriate permissions from the user, I can write and read from the Open Graph API, which in theory will allow me to do almost anything.

The problem is that I would like to use some of [Facebook's social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). In particular, I would like to implement the [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) so that it automatically appears for each blog post, article and page.

The problem is that the like button and the various Facebook plugins require an `app_id`. I would prefer not requiring users to add the developer app to their account and creating an app to get an `app_id` as it can be a confusing process for non-developers.

Is there anyway we can create or retrieve an `app_id` from open graph (which we can store and use to generate the like buttons and other facebook widgets)?

With the [migrations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/), I understand that each liked URL will not have it's own page. Once the user clicks a like button on your site, he automatically likes your page. However, let's say I have a page called `http://www.mystore.com/products/some-awesome-product` and there are other similiar pages, all with a like button. Is it possible that when clicking like, the user automatically likes our Facebook page, but when an item is published in their news feed for the like, the URL links to that specific product? Effectively, is there a way for users to like multiple pages from my site?

Update: It looks like we can [generate `app_id`s programmatically](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/10/13/making-it-easier-to-build-with-facebook/) with the create application API in the legacy REST API. However, this does not seem to be an option with the graph API.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not do-able. Even the Wordpress for Facebook plugin - https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/, requires each user to setup a facebook app and use the appid/secret to create the plugins.

Comment: FYI: At least the like button does _not_ require an app id, if you use the iframe version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the iframe version is no longer avaliable. With the migration (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/) I think the app_id is a must anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we cannot programatically create an app_id for an account. This is not an issue, as we will just create a small guide to guide our users through creating an app and submitting the app_id to us using a form. Not perfect, but should be easy to implement.

As for URLs, liking something will not automatically like your Facebook page. If `href` is blank, the current page will be liked. If you set your facebook page in the `href` parameter, then your facebook page will be liked.